# Problem with JSON dumps with custom objects

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python, trying to get json dump of of custom object, but it is giving empty objects.

`"{\n    \"ID_12\": {}\n}",`

Here 'data' do not have a specific class or model, it can be any json content.

```
import json

data = '{"name": "venkat"}'
results = {}
results["ID_12"] = type("", (object,), json.loads(data))()

print(json.dumps(
        results, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4
    ),))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is a static member, not an instance member; thus, it is found on `type(o).__dict__`, not on `o.__dict__`.

I believe using this lambda instead might help:

```
lambda o: { k: getattr(o, k) for k in dir(o) if not k.startswith("__") }
```

`dir` tries to collect all the key names available for an object, including static and inherited ones, but there will be lots of magic members (like `__dict__`) which should be filtered out.